# ajax call to rest api in jquery no longer works, caused by expired ssl certificated?

Tags: rest, jquery, ssl

I have an existing app that logs in to the server with an ajax call to a REST service. It's been working fine for a few months now. However, recently it has stopped working. The ajax call always return on .error

I have not touched the code for the app nor the server code. Logging in through the same REST service through the browser still works, so nothing wrong with that.

The only difference I can see is that the SSL certificate we have has expired. Could this be the cause?

A little more info. My app was written with Cordova for both the iOS and android. Neither of them are working right now for these calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this would be the cause of the problem.

Unless you've explicitly told your browser to ignore the warning (semi-permanently at least), there is no opportunity for an AJAX call to display the full browser warning asking you whether you want to continue despite the fact the certificate has expired. (Note that typical users shouldn't ignore invalid certificate warnings anyway.)

As a result, browsers do the right thing and make the XHR call fail in this case.

You simply need to install a certificate that's both recognised by your clients and valid in date and time.

Comment: 1+ but browsers should really warn users at least once for each page, not prompt for actions.